# HTTP interceptor not triggering

Tags: angular

My interceptor isn't triggering. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I have tried every solution I could find.

Interceptor is just not intercepting http requests. So 'Authorization' header isn't getting added.

`token.interseptor.ts` (tried `OnInit` to see if console log is getting triggered or not)

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor, OnInit {

  constructor(private AuthService: AuthService) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Working? ');

  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('request- ', request);
    const tokenizedReq = request.clone({
      setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.AuthService.getToken()}` }
    });

    return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
  }
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './utility/token.interceptor';

 providers: [ 
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
```

Sending HTTP API calls like this:

```
  const userPackage = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  }

  const respose = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/user/login', userPackage)
  const loggedIn = await respose.json();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- please use [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) to make API calls, this is angular default service for making API calls. `fetch` APIs do not go through interceptor, but httpClient APIs do go through it!

code

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
...
callFunc() {
    const respose = await 
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/api/user/login', userPackage)
    return response;
}
```

[reference stackblitz for http client not by me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-httpclient-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fdata.service.ts)

- NgOnInit does not work on services, instead use `constructor` to call any code you might want to use!